# UsedRange.Offset gives run time error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet , I am trying to filter the data and then want to paste the filtered rows to another workbook.

The below code

```
MySheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(MySheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

gives an error "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" during run time but surprisingly same code works fine when I try to debug line by line.

Not able to understand what makes a difference between debug v/s directly running the above code.

Any pointers would help.

Thanks

Comment: This line of code is trying to do multiple things. Can you also post the version of the code doing this line by line?

Comment: Please add more code for context.  It would be useful to know for example where/how `MySheet` is set.

Comment: This is the error when only **one row** is the UsedRange. In this case Resize(0) throws the error. But this not explain the line by line difference.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Filtered Data When Bottom Blank Rows

```
Sub AutoFilterCopyBottomBlanks()
    
    Const TURN_OFF_AUTOFILTER As Boolean = True
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim MySheet As Worksheet: Set MySheet = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Reference the table range ('trg')
    ' excluding any consecutive bottom-most rows that are blank.
    
    Dim trg As Range, drCount As Long
    
    With MySheet
        ' Turn off auto filtering (for the 'Find' method to work correctly).
        ' Also, make sure there are no hidden rows because the 'Find' method
        ' due to 'xlValues' will fail if any consecutive bottom-most rows
        ' are hidden.
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        ' Note that '.ShowAllData' is unsafe since the auto filter could
        ' be applied to only a portion of the range.
        With .UsedRange
            Dim lcell As Range:
            Set lcell = .Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
            If lcell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' the worksheet is blank
            drCount = lcell.Row - .Row ' data rows (header row excluded)
            If drCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only a single row (headers!?)
            Set trg = .Resize(drCount + 1)
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Apply the filter (modify as required).
    trg.AutoFilter 1, "Criteria" '
        
    ' Attempt to reference the filtered rows ('vrg' - visible range).
    Dim vrg As Range:
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if no cells found
        Set vrg = trg.Resize(drCount).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Turn off auto filtering. It is optional in case of copying.
    ' It is a necessary step to not to have to delete
    ' entire rows when deleting the filtered rows.
    If TURN_OFF_AUTOFILTER Then
        MySheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    If vrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no filtered rows
    
    ' Continue with the copy code...
    vrg.Copy

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is not visible data (all data rows are hidden), OP's code raises 1004.

Please try.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim c As Range, mysheet As Worksheet
    Set mysheet = ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set c = mysheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(mysheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        c.Copy
    Else
        MsgBox "No data"
    End If
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: I got "No cells were found"

Comment: I have checked, the filter criteria does return the rows. This is also explained by the fact that line by line debug does not throw the error. so it is still baffling my as to why it throws error at run time.

Comment: @Blackcat May I know what's your testing scenario?

Comment: @Alok - Do you have "break on all errors" set in your VB options?

Comment: One thing which I noticed was that usedrange is returning 1048576 rows which I believe is equal to max rows in Excel, when I delete all the empty rows from the bottom of the sheet, the usedrange returns a lower number and code works fine. Is there a more optimal way in VBA to ensure that I select only the last available row data, instead of relying on usedrange which is returning a huge number.

Comment: This is not from your code, but if there are `all data rows hidden`

Comment: If the `UsedRange` is ***all*** rows, then you can't reference a new range with `.Offset(1, 0)` as this would be outside the sheet boundaries.

Comment: @Alok  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba